# Ruby Rails insert ActiveRecord query in my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I'm trying to perform a query of "SpiritTrial" model where "trlid" have 7th and 8th digit = "TI", then I want to insert the objects it finds into model TiTrial and I would like to take the "trlid" from the SpiritTrial model and redefine it as "name" in TiTrial.  Here's where I'm at in TiTrial.rb  I'm getting the right stuff back I'm just having a hard time translating the documentation out there in to what I need it to do....any help is super appreciated as always.

```
def spiritpull
  u = SpiritTrial.where("trlid LIKE (?)", "%%%%%%TI%")

end
```

Comment: `%` with LIKE is like `.*` in a regex so `"%%%%%%TI%"` is a long winded and confusing way of saying `"%TI%"`. Perhaps you want `_` (which is like `.` in a regex).

Comment: So "______TI%" is more appropriate?  I see that it SEEMS to return what i need in the rails console.  but I just want 7th and 8th to equal TI, then who cares after that, could be seven or ten digits after, the % works in this case, right?

Comment: Yes, use `_` if you care about how many. `%%%%%%TI%` (which is equivalent to `%TI%`) will match anything that has `TI` anywhere and that's not what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
def spiritpull
  u = SpiritTrial.where("trlid LIKE (?)", "%%%%%%TI%")
  # you should have multiple u results, iterate through each
  u.each do |spirit|
    # create a new TiTrial for each spirit
    r = TiTrial.new(name: spirit.trlid)
    # don't forget to save
    r.save
  end
end
```

Take each `SpiritTrial` and create a new TiTrial per my above comments. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to use a sql function, It depends you DMNS, sometimes ActiveRecord is not the best option to perform sql, I think you should create a function that perform your query and insert in your table. I recommend to you keep tracking your sql using a migration like this http://www.rigelgroupllc.com/blog/2014/09/14/working-with-complex-sql-statements/